# CMake: export third party headers to directory

Tags: cmake

Using CMake I am using a third party library, TinyThread++, it is a simple Thread library wrapper and only contains 1 source files and 2 header files.

In my project CMakeList.txt I added the following line:

```
add_library(TinyThread STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../third_party/TinyThread/source/tinythread.cpp)
```

And then added a dependency to this library to the my executable this is working great.

I am trying to figure out how to copy or export the two header files to a common include directory I am using in my project.

```
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to "use" those headerfiles while compiling, you can use [include_directories()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainclude_directories) like Naszta explains.

In case you really want to copy the files, you can use [configure_file()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aconfigure_file) or [file( COPY ... )](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afile) (check the bottom of the section on the file() command).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
SET(TINY_THREAD_INCLUDE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" CACHE PATH "TinyThread include path")
SET(TINY_THREAD_SOURCE_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tinythread.cpp" CACHE FILEPATH "TinyThread source file")
...
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${TINY_THREAD_INCLUDE_PATH})
ADD_LIBRARY(TinyThread STATIC ${TINY_THREAD_SOURCE_FILE})
```

This way you could reuse them later by their name. If you would like to hide them in normal mode:

```
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(TINY_THREAD_INCLUDE_PATH TINY_THREAD_SOURCE_FILE)
```